# Bluebird, returning data but getting new promise created but not returned... react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, redux, bluebird

I keep seeming to be having this same problem where I get this same error of:

`A new promise was created but was not returned`

[image]

I am returning the data at the end of the .then block however and can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. I even just had this problem and replicated the code but seem to be getting the same error.

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.user.currentUser == null) {
      this.props
        .currentUser()
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
          return data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          return err;
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: For your own enrichment, bluebird is no longer necessary. ES6 has promises incorporated in its standard.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening from another promise that was being thrown. I had just `return` instead of `return null`. I know that this may not directly answer this strict case, but it worked for me.

This is just something I thought would be helpful. So if you get this problem and you find yourself with a promise chain and have

```
.then(() => {
  return;
})
```

change this to

```
.then(() => {
  return null;
})
```

and it should clear up that warning. Bluebird says only to use this if you know what you are doing however so if it creates strange acting code I would reconsider how you are using your promise.

Answer (score -1):

Never tried react/redux, but does returning the actual promise work? 'return this.props'

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.user.currentUser == null) {
      return this.props
        .currentUser()
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
          return data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          return err;
        });
}
```

}